# Count SQL Query Assistance

Tags: sql

I am learning how to use SQL and can't seem to work out how to do this kind of query.
The data set has a list of male and female school results which are allocated a score.

```
LearningArea    YearLevel   AchievementResult   Gender  NumericalScore
ENGLISH            1               A               M          1
ENGLISH            1               C               M          3
ENGLISH            1               C               F          3
ENGLISH            1               B               F          2
```

I am trying to analyse the data to show the total score for males and the total score for females without having to do 2 queries.
I have tried myself and looked around but I have only been able to do it with 2 queries.

```
SELECT Count(Score) AS Male
FROM Data
WHERE Gender = "M"
```

&

```
SELECT Count(Score) AS Female
FROM Data
WHERE Gender = "F"
```

All I'm looking for is anyone that knows of a way to make this one query.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Gender,Count(*) AS Number 
FROM Data
GROUP BY Gender
```

Based upon the text of your question, you may want `SUM` instead of `COUNT` but I'm sure you can work it out from here.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **case**:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = "M" then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Male",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Gender = "F" then 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "Female"
FROM Data
```